# How to Create Views for all Tables in my DB

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, view

I have written the code below to correct all table in my db.
Please review and correct it.

```sql
Declare
Name Varchar2(100);
A Number:=0;

Cursor C1 Is 
Select Table_Name From Tabs;

Begin
Open C1;
Loop
A:=A+1;
Fetch C1 Into Name;
Exit When C1%Notfound;
Execute Immediate 'Create Or Replace View Tab||A
                  As
                  Select * From Name';

End Loop;

Close C1;

End
```

Please correct my Code

Comment: [TAB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/TAB.html) is ancient and deprecated, and includes views and dropped objects. You probably want `user_tables`. (This is for tables in your schema only, not the whole database as suggested in the question title.)

Comment: What would be the use of a view called `tab37` defined as `select * from order_details` (for example)?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I agree that `user_tables` would be better, but he used `TABS`, which is a synonym to user_tables, not `TAB`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/TABS.html#GUID-232471C5-307C-4866-BA55-0DB57C214B96

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Oops, good spot.

Comment: Well, correct or not, the entire exercise seems pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum is not a place to give people assigments, please ask questions about the issue you are running into and we are willing to help you. Please try doing a better job next time.

Your execute immediate string should be:

```
Execute Immediate 
  'Create Or Replace View Tab' ||A|| '
   As
   Select * From ' || Name;
```

and don't forget the `;` after the final `end`

Comment: Thanks a lot . Next time will avoid this

Comment: If this answered your question, you could mark it as answered. That will indicate to other forum members that the question has been solved and will give the person who answered the question some credits. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

fixed your code:

```sql
Declare
   Name Varchar2(100);
   A Number:=0;
   Cursor C1 Is 
      Select Table_Name From Tabs;
Begin
   Open C1;
   Loop
      A:=A+1;
      Fetch C1 Into Name;
      Exit When C1%Notfound;
      Execute Immediate 'Create Or Replace View Tab'||A||'
                        As
                        Select * From "'||Name||'"';
   End Loop;
   Close C1;
End;
/
```

But I would do something like this:

```sql
declare
   procedure p_exec(pCMD in varchar2, pPrintOnly varchar2 default 'n') is
   begin
      if pPrintOnly='y' then
         dbms_output.put_line(pCMD);
      else
         execute immediate pCMD;
         dbms_output.put_line(pCMD);
      end if;
   end;
begin
   for r in (Select rownum rn, Table_Name From Tabs) loop
      p_exec(
         utl_lms.format_message(
            'Create Or Replace View Tab%s As Select * From "%s"'
           , to_char(r.rn,'fm9999')
           , r.table_name
         )
         -- ,'y' -- << uncomment to print commands only without execution
      );
   end loop;
end;
/
```